# How to place a non-interactive rectangle on top of a map

Tags: javascript, mapbox, mapbox-gl-js

I want to place a rectangle on a mapbox map positioned absolutely compared to the map container itself.

I want a rectangle like this: https://docs.mapbox.com/playground/static/

What I tried is:

```
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Display a map on a webpage</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1,maximum-scale=1,user-scalable=no">
<link href="https://api.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v2.8.2/mapbox-gl.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://api.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v2.8.2/mapbox-gl.js"></script>
<style>
body { margin: 0; padding: 0; }
#map {  top: 0; bottom: 0; width: 500px; height: 400px; }
#container {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 100;
    top: 50%;  /* position the top  edge of the element at the middle of the parent */
    left: 50%; /* position the left edge of the element at the middle of the parent */

    transform: translate(-50%, -50%); 
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="map">
<div id="container">
     <div style="width:300px;height:200px;border:1px solid #000;">test</div>
   </div> 


</div>
<script>
    mapboxgl.accessToken = 'XXX';
const map = new mapboxgl.Map({
container: 'map', // container ID
style: 'mapbox://styles/mapbox/streets-v11', // style URL
center: [-74.5, 40], // starting position [lng, lat]
zoom: 9 // starting zoom,
})
</script>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

The problem is that the rectangle is not interactive. I can't zoom in or out when hoovering in the rectangle area. I also tried to make a layer in mapbox I couldn't get it to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution. Pointer-events: none; must be added to interact with the underlaying layer and not the rectangle.

```
<div id="container" style=" pointer-events: none;">
     <div style="width:300px;height:200px;border:1px solid #000; pointer-events: none;">test</div>
   </div>
```

I found the solution here:

> The pointer-events CSS property sets under what circumstances (if any)
> a particular graphic element can become the target of pointer events.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events